# Burninate [crash]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash) tag (x5776) seems unnecessary to me.

- Nobody can be an expert at crashes.
- It is not useful (I highly doubt it that anyone searches for [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash))
- Used for all types of errors/exceptions for all languages
- 74% (!) of the questions already contain "crash" in the title ([query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197149/tag-occurence-in-title?TagName=crash))
- Only 35 followers

Can we burninate it?

Comment: No, please don't.  Although it's misused, there is a legitimate case for keeping it around.  As an example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481783/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-a-c-program-crash).

Comment: @devnull Does that actually help categorize the question better than searching title or body text?

Comment: Agree with the OP to burn this tag even if I can become crash expert if I want http://images.brisbanetimes.com.au/2010/06/22/1623462/Dummy1-420x0.jpg :)

Comment: It has 35 followers. Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: perhaps a general crash tag is unneccessary, and should be replaced with platform or language specific crash tags where (and IF) appropriate. eg android-crash, iOS-crash ? I note there are a few of those. But as the OP said, I can't imagine a scenario where people search for a crash tag rather than a specific language, framework or platform, etc.

Comment: Such questions often fall into the unique category of debugging an issue when it's not yet apparent what the source of the crash is.  Each platform usually has certain techniques and tools for doing this.  Entire books are devoted to this subject, and there are indeed experts on the subject.  I think the best you could do if you are set on this is to retag to platform specific, otherwise I think you are doing more harm than good.

Comment: Oh, I know at least one expert in crashes. The person crashed a company's central web server. Central Sybase server. Multiple app servers. An entire WAN once (don't ask). No, wasn't me! :)

Comment: Crash and burninate ...

Comment: In a past life, I wrote a system for tracking and diagnosing crashes and followed with great interest the writings of a small group of experts who made it their business to document this rather under-appreciated craft. See Hans' answer for a longer rebuttal.

Answer (score 40):

There can be experts at crashes.  I'm one of the two currently listed with a substantial number of answers, user Kerni is the other one.

SO is well aware of this, they push these kind of questions on my personal front page.  The tag filters I use limit my exposure to the kind of crashes I can solve so it is not just "all types for all languages".  I'm getting close to 3 votes per answer, better than average so it certainly looks like other SO users actually consider them useful.  Not entirely a mystery, if you have to deal with a hard-to-diagnose crash then you really do need all the help you can get.

Kinda shot down all of your bullets here :)  Do keep in mind that SO has a very long tail, not everything that's at the far end of it is entertainment to everybody.

Comment: The tag [crash] is on the fourth page of your "tags-tab"...

Comment: That just means that my tag filter works well, I don't pretend that I can solve every crash in every runtime environment.

Answer (score 25):

I would agree with jammypeach, that it could be replaced with other, more specific tags, for example segmentation fault or even better exceptions/errors, i.e. outofmemory or something like that.

As you said, a crash could be caused by almost anything, and the tag doesn't help much. By default the problems people have are unexpected results or crashes (exceptions/errors).

To me the crash tag seems as necessary as an error tag.

Comment: Or "as unnecessary".

Comment: Keep in mind its not always apparent what the source of a crash is until significant amount of debugging is done.  So there's alot of cases where its probably difficult to retag it segmentation fault, exception, etc.

Comment: I agree with @AaronLS.  If you can tag it exactly e.g. [OutOfMemoryError] [GLib] you're already much of the way towards fixing it.  We shouldn't require people asking questions know key parts of the answer, just that they do good-faith research/searching first.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt someone will search for a crash tag, but it can be a useful "second tag" in a search to narrow crash-related problems for the main tag.

Comment: It will be useful as a second tag only if users add it as a tag. I suspect most don't.

Answer (score 5):

I have mixed feelings about this tag. My final conclusion is that it should be kept for the time being, but that as soon as the Internet is full up it should be the first thing to be deleted.

Comment: Good candidate for first delete, we could also delete this page: http://theendofinternet.com/

Comment: @miltonb Shouldn't that page be *last*?

Answer (score -6):

Having recently written something to randomly cause crashes in a code base as resilience testing ... id say it does have a very niche application.

In a few years this will be far more relevant as people adopt more distributed languages imo