# Is [runtime-error] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [runtime-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runtime-error) tag has 2,611 questions and from what I can tell, there is no rhyme or reason. The languages are all over the place and the tag wiki isn't very useful. I would bet at least half of the questions on SO involve runtime errors. So should this be burninated, or am I missing some useful function of this tag?

Comment: Closely related: [Burninate \[crash\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255483)