# Should the [freeze] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813710/mongodb-server-freeze-large-amount-of-collections) which is tagged with [freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freeze). The tag wiki says:

> freeze in programming refers to a condition where in the concerned code or system becomes unresponsive.

Glancing through the option questions, I don't see any pattern (crosses programming languages, platforms, and tools). There's also only one follower.

Does it make sense to keep this tag or to burninate it?

### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes, I think so, albeit it's a general class of "stuff becomes unresponsive."

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, I think so.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Hmm, I don't think so. Most of the existing questions also include the word "freeze" in their titles. It also has only one follower.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes. But they are quite a range of contexts.

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) on MSE or the [unofficial SOCVR process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323121/4174897) on MSO.

Comment: Related [Burninate \[crash\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255483)

Comment: Can you please go over the [process for burninating](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags) and elaborate in your question how the tag passes or fails the [four criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

Comment: A tag being used across platforms and tools is not always a sign for a bad tag. From the 15 or so questions I checked most of them are about some software becoming unresponsive, two where about freezing columns/windows. It might need a clean-up and some closing of off-topic stuff but the tag seems to be used correctly in most cases.

Comment: @rene those are excellent points, thakns; I've updated my post. I'm not sure it should be burninated anymore (I used to be under the assumption that the rule of thumb is "if nobody will follow it because it's too diverse, it's a useless meta-tag").

Comment: Another reason for burnination: [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) is a static method in JavaScript and there is already [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293321/opposite-of-object-freeze-or-object-seal-in-javascript) using this tag for that purpose... (already edited)

Comment: And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70576894/12299000) from 15 days ago using "freeze" in the same sense of "making immutable" but not in the context of Javascript.

Answer (score 12):

[freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freeze) is a meta tag and should be burninated.

A person cannot be an expert in [freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freeze). The conditions which result in the freeze of a system can be of many origins and we have more suitable tags for this <sup>1</sup>:

- Accidentally walking into a [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deadlock)
- Wrong use of [locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locking)
- Wrong use of [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wait)
- Having a too large [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timeout) and the target (server, hardware, anything 3rd party) is unresponsive
- ...

---

<sup>1</sup> Note this list is not complete. These are just off the top of my head

Comment: I just used it: When typing in `freeze` it's suggested to "see also `hang`", but there is no `hang` tag. I even tried to edit the `freeze` tag, but could not even find a reference to `hang`.

Comment: @U.Windl do you have an example question where you tried to use it? I'm still convinced the question wouldn't need the `freeze` nor the `hang` tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76810979/6607497

Answer (score 9):

I think the OP is too generous.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** 
No, it describes a symptom of a problem which could have many different causes and solutions, which are unrelated to each other; but a problem is not the same thing as a question. And it doesn't describe a specific symptom unambiguously (see #4).

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** 
No. Programs "freezing" in the sense of becoming unresponsive is not "unique to software development", every computer user sometimes has to deal with programs which freeze.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** 
No, it adds barely more information than just saying the program "doesn't work", which is useless and vague. It cannot help answerers find questions within their area of expertise because "programs freezing" isn't an area of expertise.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** 
No, it could mean that the computer hard-locks or [BSODs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death) becoming totally unresponsive to any user input, needing a hard reboot; it could mean a program becomes permanently unresponsive, needing to be killed from the command line or task manager; it could mean the program takes a long time to do some computation and becomes temporarily unresponsive until the computation completes; it could mean the program takes a long time to do some computation and remains responsive to user input but only very slowly.

Comment: I disagree on #2 and #3: When seeing "freeze" as permanently being non-responsive (as opposed to "occasional temporary delayed response") it's *not true* that "every computer user sometimes has to deal with programs which freeze", meaning: "It's **not** expected". Also I don't see "freeze" as a synonym for "*does not work*", because the latter is much wider (less specific). On #4: Possible distinctions for "freeze" could be: "panic/crash" (without automatic restart) (programming error or unexpected external event), "deadlock" (programming error), "infinite loop" (programming error)

Answer (score 5):

I think that this tag should be removed. There could be all kinds of reasons for a program freezing, many of which have nothing to do with each other. That being said, it's difficult to see how this tag could possibly add useful information or help people find questions to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Questions relating to "freezing" in the sense of making objects immutable, like in JS or Ruby, are talking about a specific, programming related concept. I don't think that "freeze" is a good tag for this concept, but the questions should be retagged to something more appropriate.