# Should [crash] and [appcrash] crash into eachother?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I know there is [some controversy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255483/burninate-crash) over [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash), but I think [appcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcrash) is pretty much the same tag. We don't need 2 similar tags. It should be merged or synonymized.

Some stats:

- [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash) - 10118 questions
- [appcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcrash) - 177 questions

Comment: Title suggestion: Should [crash] and [appcrash] crash into eachother?

Comment: Reminds me of one of my kids' [favorite books](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/618TldY17yL.jpg)

Comment: @Machavity that looks like a truck version of Kool-Aid Man

Comment: [appcrash] [crash] crash

Comment: Pretty sure I saw someone a few hours ago removing an [[tag:appcrash]] tag. I don't remember who it was, and certainly can't go back and find it now, but just a reminder to everyone: when a retag request is brought up on Meta, it's brought up for *discussion by the community*. It is not yet time to go hunting down these questions and retagging them!

Comment: @CodyGray It looks like only 3 questions were retagged (164 -> 161 for stats). But yes, you're absolutely right

Comment: carcrash, traincrash, planecrash, appcrash, crash is all trash

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth added punny title to get some attention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tags had very similar tag wiki and related tags. I checked the first 100 questions of [appcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcrash), and the tag was being used interchangeably with the [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash) tag, and I didn't find any usages where [appcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcrash) was completely different from [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash).

I synonymized the tags in this direction: [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crash) × 10823 ← [appcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcrash) × 202